# Android Studio - Build fails on compile, cannot find dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

Here's build.gradle:

```
C:\Users\billb\StudioProjects\ShoppingList03>type build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "/com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.3/"
        compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Error is on the compile:  cannot find DefaultDependencyHandler.
I've reloaded Android SDK Platform-Tools and SDK Tools, both 26.0.1

Where is this DefaultDependencyHandler?  Why is it required?
There's something in my android java code that requires this, evidently.

Any ideas out there?  I've spent way too much time trying to track this down.

Answer (score 1):

Add `compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0"` line in your `app` level `build.gradle` file instead of `project` level `build.gradle` file.